# Add property to ko observable array items

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable array that contains objects. I want to add a "editable" property to the array after the data call. I think I just need to loop through the items and add an item.editable=false to each one but I am not sure where I would need to do this.

this is the function  my viewmodel

```
function GetemployeeDetails() {
    return employeeDataService.getEmpDetails(employeeDetails);
    }
```

Dataservice calls a function that does a ajax post.

```
var dataservice = {

        getEmpDetails: getEmpDetails
    };
```

function that populates from data

```
var getempDetails = function(employeeDetailsObservable) {
        var dataObservableArray = ko.observableArray([]);
        var newJson;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/api/employee/employeeDetailsByID/",
            data: '{}',
            async: false,
            success: function(dataIn) {
                newJson = $.parseJSON(dataIn);
            employeeDetailsObservable([]);
           newJson.forEach(function(e) {
                    var empdetails=new  emdetailsmodel(e.name,e.number)
                    employeeDetailsObservable(empdetails);
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `editable = false` (or `editable = ko.observable(false)`) inside your forEach:

```
newJson.forEach(function(e) {
  var empdetails=new  emdetailsmodel(e.name,e.number)
  empdetails.editable = false;
  employeeDetailsObservable(empdetails);
});
```

Comment: I can see that it gets added to the empdetails object but when I add it to my bindings I am getting editable not defined.